# How to update model fields using a view in DJango

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I have a problem to update a model field in a list using a view. The update run only in the first item in the list but not in the others but if i run in shell all objects is updated.

models.py

```
class Contrato(models.Model):

nome = models.CharField(u'Nome/Identificação', max_length=200)
num = models.CharField(u'Número', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
data_inicio = models.DateField(u'Data do início')
data_fim = models.DateField(u'Data do fim', editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
progress = models.IntegerField(u'progresso',editable=False, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

...

views.py

```
def index(request):

vigentes = Contrato.objects.all()
vigentes_total = Contrato.objects.filter(status='0').order_by('nome').count() 

h = datetime.date.today()

print vigentes

for v in vigentes:

    d = v.data_fim - v.data_inicio
    dif = h - v.data_inicio
    v.progress = int((float(dif.days) / float(d.days))*100)
    v.save()


template = loader.get_template('contratos/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
'vigentes': vigentes,
})

if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponse("You are not logged in.")

else:       
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Edit.

If I change the view to:

```
def index(request):


vigentes = Contrato.objects.all()

print vigentes

for item in vigentes:
    print item 


template = loader.get_template('contratos/index.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'vigentes': vigentes,
    'vigentes_total': vigentes_total,
})

if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponse("You are not logged in.")

else:       
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I see only the first item. The problem is the for loop in the view.

Comment: `progress` field is defined as a CharField, why are you setting an `int`?

Comment: Please show the completed view, and fix your indentation.

Comment: Thank You. I can change the field to int, but this don't solve the update problem.

Comment: Problem solved.

The for loop dont run in a view. I use django-cron (https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) to run update in all models in list.